# Не доступны сайты на VDS

Tags: vds

Сегодня начал устанавливать сертификат *SLL* на домен. Поставил на порт `443` Теперь все сайты на *VDS* не доступ. Помогите, пожалуйста. Все сайты возглашают ошибку

> 502 Bad Gateway

Answer (score 1):

`502 Bad Gateway` отдает *nginx*, значит *nginx* работает.По данной ошибке можно понять, что *nginx* не может связаться с *appache*.Проверяйте запускается ли вообще *apache*, и на какой порту он пытается запускаться.Возможно, что у Вас *nginx* и *apache* запускаются оба на `80` порту. Из за чего очень часто такое и бывает. *nginx* запустился, а *apache* пишет в лог, что порт уже используется кем то.

Answer (score 0):

Копайте настройки Апача и нгинкса